# Changing the step on the x-axis on the plot in matplotlib.pylab

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have considered the matrix of numbers as the mapping of plane points to their values and then draw the isoline. I have practised the contour function from the following module: matplitlib.pylab and I have succeeded in configurating it as I wanted, but there is one exeption. - The contourf set a step by default and it designates the values on the Y-axis and X-axis. I would like to change it. Is it possible? I have read all of the documentation about the contour function but I haven't found the solution. I am a beginner. This is my code:

```
plt.figure()
cs = plt.contour(m.Z, levels=A, colors=K, linestyles='solid')
plt.clabel(cs, A[1::2], inline=0.5, fmt='%1.0f', fontsize=10)
plt.colorbar(cs, shrink=1)
plt.show()
```

m.Z is my matrix and plt is matplotlib.pylab I have tried to change the step giving the values of vectors - X and Y in contour ( I know that they aren't needed) but it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by the "step" on the x-axis?  Do you mean the tick marks?  If so, how exactly do you want to change them (change the extent, change the spacing, etc.)?